# What does the starred expression do in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, operator-keyword

I know that the starred expression in python does this:

```
>>> a, *b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[2, 3, 4]
```

And this:

```
>>> def test(*args):
    print(args)
>>> test(1, 2, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

So what is it doing in this line? This line is supposed to [group a list into sequential n-tuples](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/303060-group-a-list-into-sequential-n-tuples/).

```
zip(*[lst[i::n] for i in range(n)])
```

What does the star do? I tried to get its value, but it gives me an error:

```
>>> a = *[1, 2, 3, 4]
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

And when I tried it with a sample list:

```
>>> zip(*[1, 2,3, 4])
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

What does this mean? Aren't lists iterable? I must not be understanding a key concept with the star operator (if it's an operator). Please explain. (I'm using Python 3.5.2 if that helps.)

Comment: Note that the list comprehension results in a *nested* list being passed to `zip`; the error is telling you that the first element of your list is not iterable, not that the list itself is not iterable.